# Images from the database not displaying in react when using DRF

Tags: reactjs, django, django-rest-framework

When data from the database is serialized, the images stop displaying in react but {product.image} shows the path of the image. Please I want to know why the image isn't displaying in react but is working perfectly in django. Whenever I click on the image link in the admin page the product gets displayed. The images displayed in react when fetching the products as python array from django, but when I turn to drf it stops displaying. I'm using Django 4.0, I have no Idea whether this has any effect on the issue. When using  DRF, EVERY OTHER PROPERTY OF THE PRODUCT IS BEING DISPLAYED IN REACT EXCEPT THE IMAGE

```
Here's the part of the React component where the image is referenced

 <Link to={`/product/${product._id}`}. 
    <Card.Img src={product.image} />
</Link>
```

```
urlpatterns = [
    path('admin/', admin.site.urls),
    path('', include('base.urls'))
]
 
urlpatterns += static(settings.MEDIA_URL, document_root=settings.MEDIA_ROOT)
```

```
STATIC_URL = 'static/'
MEDIA_URL = '/images/'  STATICFILES_DIR = [     BASE_DIR / 'static' ] 
MEDIA_ROOT = 'static/images
```

Comment: Can you show us product serializer ? In general, check if the image field is included in it or by mistake you put it in the exclude list

Answer (score 0):

I think for the source you should give url :

```html
<Card.Img src={product.image.url} />
```